# Loop through list elements, and add class if list element contains another list

Tags: jquery, list, loops, addition

Pretty simple problem here, but it's been bugging me a bit.

I've got an accordion menu set up like so:

```
<ul id="menu" class="navigation">
    <li><a href="#"><span>Dashboard</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Articles &amp; Posts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon_articles">Articles &amp; Posts</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Articles &amp; Posts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon_pages">Pages</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon_media">Media Gallery</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Articles &amp; Posts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon_calendar">Calendar</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon_demos">Features &amp; Demos</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Articles &amp; Posts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon_settings">Settings</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon_logout">Logout</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

And I've got a jQuery script that runs the accordion:

```
function accordionMenu() {
$('ul.navigation ul').hide();
$('ul.navigation li a').click(
    function() {
        var parentElement = this.parentNode.parentNode.id;
        var elementTest = $(this).next();

        if((elementTest.is('ul')) && (elementTest.is(':visible'))) {
            $('#' + parentElement + ' ul:visible').slideUp('fast');
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            return false;
        }
        if((elementTest.is('ul')) && (!elementTest.is(':visible'))) {
            $('#' + parentElement + ' ul:visible').slideUp('fast');
            elementTest.slideDown('fast');
            $('ul.navigation a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            return false;
        }
    }
);
}

$(document).ready(function() {accordionMenu();});
```

Now I need to figure out how to loop through the list items, and find the ones that have lists following them (ie, the ones that when clicked, drop down to reveal the hidden list.). Then I need to add a span on the end of each one (inbetween </a> and <ul>). That's it really. It's just confusing me - how should I go about doing it?

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: The title of your question says you want to add a class, but the question itself says you want to append a `<span>` element - which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('ul.navigation').children().has("ul").each(function(){
    $(this).children("a").append("<span>test</span>");              
});
```

this should work :) good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#menu ul").each(function(){
    $(this).closest("li").addClass("whatever_class_you_need")
        .find("a").first().after("<span>something goes here</span>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The [:has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector is perfect for this scenario.

```
$("#menu li:has(ul)").addClass("hasSubMenu");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
$('ul.navigation li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).children('ul').length > 0;
}).each(function(){
    $(this).find('a').after('<spam />');
})
.addClass('className');
```